# Can אֱלֹהִ֑ים be considered singular if the singular form אֱלֹ֣הֵי exists and is used?

Tags: hebrew

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elohim) states:

> The word elohim or 'elohiym (ʼĕlôhîym) is a grammatically plural noun
> for "gods" or "deities" or various other words in Biblical Hebrew

And:

> In Hebrew, the ending -im normally indicates a masculine plural.
> However, when referring to the Jewish God, Elohim is usually
> understood to be grammatically singular (i.e. it governs a singular
> verb or adjective).

I reasearched a bit and it seems that the orthodox jew will use arguments to regard that it is singular. 
Such as: ***מַיִם*** translated is ***water*** (sing.), or ***שָׁמַיִם*** is translated ***sky*** (sing.)

The trinitarian view will use arguments towards the plurality of the word, pointing that God is not just one person.

All biases aside, the question is:
Can אֱלֹהִ֑ים be considered singular if the singular form אֱלֹ֣הֵי exists and is used?

[There are 680 englishman's ocurrences of אֱלֹהִ֑ים.](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/elohim_430.htm) 
[And there are 398 englishman's of אֱלֹ֣הֵי.](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/elohei_430.htm)

Ex: Gen 1.1 בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם
And genesis 28:13. אֲנִ֣י יְהוָ֗ה אֱלֹהֵי֙ אַבְרָהָ֣ם אָבִ֔יךָ

Comment: What you are calling singular is the plural construct, i.e. the God of...

Comment: 'Without bible passages'?. What about the 1.078 passages linked?

Comment: Hi snoopy! Are you narrowing the scope of the question to only Genesis 1:1 and Genesis 28:13?

Comment: Asking this because it's very unlikely you'll have someone looking at the 1000 occurrences in order to answer (which is why it makes the question unsuitable). Narrowing down the scope could be the solution.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁, ok, thanks!

Comment: Elohim is singular as the authors use singular verbal conjugation when elohim is the subject of an action.  Yes, it shares the plural ending like waters, but whenever it appears, the verbs indicate it is singular.

Comment: Simply listing verses with the word doesn't make this question *about* those verses. Sorry, but we don't have general questions on the Biblical languages here.

Comment: Gus is correct. While the noun in a plural form, it is used as the subject of singular verbs.